# Open file in new GVim window within a single session

Tags: editor, vim

I would like to have two windows opened while running a single GVim session. Just like tabs but placed in two separate windows. This kind of setup is handy for dual screen setup. I haven't found anything relevant in the manual. Is it possible?

Comment: `:!gvim otherfile` and alt-tab (or whatever your OS uses)?  :)

Comment: thanks, but this is separate session, opening same files will cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible I'm afraid.  I'd suggest you send an email to the mailing list with a feature request.  I can see that it would be useful, but you'd need to have a lot of extra keyboard commands equivalent to `Ctrl-W h` to switch between different windows.

It's also very GUI specific and most of the functionality in Vim is designed to work in both the GUI and the TUI.

Comment: Agreed, this is probably impossible — In MacVim, which supports multiple windows, they are treated as separate instances.